# I want to filter and copy data to another sheet according to each filter. (Google Apps Script)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering

I am having a few issues. I have a sheet called (RF) in which I have information divided by places (Passenger seat, driver seat, etc), each one is identified with a number (1, 2, 3, 4. Four is the amount of categories but it could change so that is why I am trying a loop). Something like this:
[image: info]

So what I am trying to do is to iterate through each of the rows and filter them by the number on column A (as I said I would need to do it someway through a loop or something because those "numbers" I use as identifiers may vary). Once it's filtered, I am trying to copy the filtered data to a new sheet called just like the number. But it's just not working. I solve an error and then another one occurs and it's driving me crazy.

I've seen a few posts on StackOverFlow trying to get close to my problem but I have not found any solution.

```
function bucleInicialPrueba(){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var hojaRF = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RF');
    var ultFila = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('RF').getLastRow();
    var data = hojaRF.getDataRange().getValues();
    spreadsheet.getRange('1:156').activate();
    hojaRF.getRange('1:156').createFilter();
    for(j=0;j<=data.length;j++){
      if(data[j][0]!=j){
        hojaRF.hideRows(j+1);
        hojaRF.getRange('A1').activate();
        for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
          var filter = hojaRF.getFilter();
          if (filter!=null) {
            var criterio = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();
            criterio.whenNumberEqualTo(i).build();
            hojaRF.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(i, criterio);
            spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);
            spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(i);
            hojaRF.getRange('A'+ j + ':AK' +       j).copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(i).getActiveRange(),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
            hojaRF.getFilter().remove();
          } else {
            var criterio = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();
            criterio.whenNumberEqualTo(i).build();
            hojaRF.getRange(1, 1, hojaRF.getLastRow()).createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(i, criterio);
            spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);
            spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(i);   
            hojaRF.getRange('A'+ j + ':AK' + j).copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(i).getActiveRange(),SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)          
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the information to actually be copied?? You could just set a Query in each category sheet. For example, in A1 of the Category Sheet you could set this function in B1:

> =query(RF!1:156,"Select * Where A = "&A1)

---

This is with the range of your code, but probably your amount of rows will be increasing (probably the columns won't), so you should better say:

> =query(RF!A1:Z,"Select * Where A = "&A1)

I've said Z, but you can stablish the column you want

Answer (score 0):

With this function vs1 now contains the lines you want:

```
function bucleInicialPrueba(n=2) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange(2,1,sh1.getLastRow() - 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(r => r[0].toString().includes(n)).filter(e => e);
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs1));
}

Execution log
4:27:58 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:27:57 PM  Info    [["2sh",4,5,15,2,3,19,14,11,10,5,7,0,1,10,6,18,4,19,1,8,4,16,1,18,19],["2sh",2,19,2,18,3,17,19,16,5,10,6,6,1,13,15,14,0,8,3,6,7,18,4,17,5],["2sh",2,16,15,9,10,5,8,4,19,4,5,16,16,1,8,3,13,4,4,19,2,1,16,16,18],["2sh",14,15,3,0,19,12,17,13,6,2,8,13,6,11,16,3,0,12,18,19,5,15,17,7,1],["2sh",7,18,13,17,18,11,1,3,16,11,0,16,9,10,19,6,14,12,16,7,2,11,13,13,16],["2sh",3,15,11,18,6,18,3,10,17,5,6,17,15,11,14,1,5,14,9,13,19,13,6,17,2],["2sh",12,16,7,9,10,7,5,14,0,4,0,6,12,6,6,17,10,15,5,15,1,3,6,12,16]]
4:27:59 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

My Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1sh | 6 | 5 | 13 | 1 | 15 | 7 | 10 |
| 1sh | 9 | 1 | 10 | 0 | 15 | 15 | 11 |
| 1sh | 6 | 16 | 4 | 11 | 14 | 0 | 10 |
| 1sh | 3 | 18 | 1 | 14 | 6 | 13 | 14 |
| 1sh | 14 | 14 | 8 | 12 | 16 | 7 | 12 |
| 1sh | 19 | 13 | 18 | 6 | 3 | 8 | 5 |
| 1sh | 6 | 15 | 18 | 9 | 12 | 17 | 17 |
| 1sh | 19 | 14 | 0 | 7 | 18 | 12 | 11 |
| 1sh | 11 | 8 | 9 | 9 | 19 | 12 | 11 |
| 1sh | 9 | 3 | 5 | 10 | 19 | 9 | 9 |
| 2sh | 4 | 5 | 15 | 2 | 3 | 19 | 14 |
| 2sh | 2 | 19 | 2 | 18 | 3 | 17 | 19 |
| 2sh | 2 | 16 | 15 | 9 | 10 | 5 | 8 |
| 2sh | 14 | 15 | 3 | 0 | 19 | 12 | 17 |
| 2sh | 7 | 18 | 13 | 17 | 18 | 11 | 1 |
| 2sh | 3 | 15 | 11 | 18 | 6 | 18 | 3 |
| 2sh | 12 | 16 | 7 | 9 | 10 | 7 | 5 |
| 3sh | 13 | 8 | 1 | 19 | 4 | 6 | 17 |
| 3sh | 1 | 8 | 8 | 17 | 4 | 15 | 6 |
| 3sh | 4 | 16 | 16 | 8 | 4 | 14 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with CriteriaBuilder, so I made an repository on [this link](https://github.com/NikolaPlusEqual/GoogleAppsScriptFilters/blob/main/Functions).

You can use function whenNumberEqualTo(number, rng, col), and iterate it, so function will look like whenNumberEqualTo(i, data, 1), where 1 <= i <= 4.

Just copy entire Functions file into your .gs code and call a desired function, or you can copy only this chunk of code and call the function whenNumberEqualTo(i, data, 1) inside the for loop:

```
var setData = {}

function whenNumberEqualTo(number, rng, col){
  if (typeof col == "number" && typeof number == "number"){
    setData.col = col;
    setData.num = number;
  }
  else{
    return;
  }
  var output = rng.filter(wnet);
  return output;
}

function wnet(ar){
  var num = setData.num;
  var col = setData.col - 1;
  return ar[col] == num;
}
```